# Is OpenShift's socket accessible from outside?

Tags: sockets, python-2.7, port, openshift

I need a socket connection, to receive byte streams, for my app that needs to be accessed from outside. [Port Forwarding](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift) only redirects HTTP traffics and binding to `$OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_IP` does not make it publicly available. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not currently a way to open a raw tcp socket to your gear on OpenShift through it's public ip.  You would have to open a port between 15,000 and 20,000 and then use rhc port forward command to access it.